# Enable and disable GameObject on onstaytrigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StayonGallery2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject G1;
    public GameObject G2;
    void Start()
    {
        G1.SetActive(false);
        G2.SetActive(false);
        
    }

    private bool _isStay;

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider player)
    {
        if (player.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            _isStay = true;
        }
           
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (_isStay)
        {
            _isStay = false;
            
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("g")) //If G is pressed
            {
                if (!G1.activeInHierarchy)
                {
                    G1.SetActive(true);
                    G2.SetActive(false);
                }
                else if (G1.activeInHierarchy)
                {
                    G1.SetActive(false);
                    G2.SetActive(true);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When I press G, G1 should activate and when I press G again, G1 will deactivate and G2 will activate.

I noticed that the frames everysecond on the Ontriggerstay causes if else statement to do it twice or trice in a single press of G.
But in this code even if I use delay, It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Unity docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html

> Note: Input flags are not reset until Update. You should make all the Input calls in the Update Loop.

Don't use `Input` in any physics callbacks, use it in `Update` or `LateUpdate`. You can record the trigger state then check keyboard state later.

```
private bool _isStay;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider player)
{
    if (player.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        _isStay = true;
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider player)
{
    if (player.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        _isStay = false;
}

void Update()
{
    if(_isStay)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("g")) //If G is pressed
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use this, and I press G, sometimes it executes, sometimes not. I have to press G multiple times for it to work.

Comment: is there a way to make more accurate?

Comment: Have you removed WaitForSeconds?

Comment: Yes, Please see the edited code. above

Comment: The problem is caused by a high frame rate, `OnTriggerStay` is not trigged between frames, try to use `OnTriggerEnter + OnTriggerExit` instead of `OnTriggerStay` and remove `_isStay = false;` in `Update`.